# Audio stream webapi on ios

Tags: jquery, ios, audio, asp.net-web-api, audio-streaming

I'would like to stream audio files on asp.net app. 
I've found some example of webapi streaming and i've wrote that :

```
  Public Class AudioController
    Inherits ApiController


    Public Function [Get](id As String) As HttpResponseMessage

        Dim T As iTunesLib.IITTrack = Global_asax.iTunesApp.LibraryPlaylist.Tracks.ItemByPersistentID(Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(id, 8), 16), Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(id, 8), 16))

        Dim filename As String = ""

        If T.Kind = ITTrackKind.ITTrackKindCD Or T.Kind = ITTrackKind.ITTrackKindFile Then
            filename = CType(T, IITFileOrCDTrack).Location
        End If
        If T.Kind = ITTrackKind.ITTrackKindURL Then
            filename = CType(T, IITURLTrack).URL
        End If

        Dim vidFile = File.OpenRead(filename)

        Return New ProgressiveDownload(Request).ResultMessage(vidFile, "audio/m4a")
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ProgressiveDownload
    Public ReadOnly Property IsRangeRequest() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Request.Headers.Range IsNot Nothing AndAlso _Request.Headers.Range.Ranges.Count > 0
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function ResultMessage(stream As Stream, mediaType As String) As HttpResponseMessage
        Try
            If IsRangeRequest Then

                Dim content = New ByteRangeStreamContent(stream, _Request.Headers.Range, mediaType)
                Dim response = _Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent)
                response.Content = content

                Return response
            Else
                Dim content = New StreamContent(stream)
                Dim response = _Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                response.Content = content
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(mediaType)

                Return response
            End If

        Catch ibr As InvalidByteRangeException
            Return _Request.CreateErrorResponse(ibr)
        Catch e As Exception
            Return _Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub New(request As HttpRequestMessage)
        _Request = request
    End Sub

    Private _Request As HttpRequestMessage
End Class
```

JS

```
function Play(sourceUrl) {
        var audio = $("#Lecteur");
        if ($('#SRC').length == 0) {
            audio.append(' <source id="SRC" type="audio/mp4" />');
        }
        $("#SRC").attr("src",'/api/audio/' + sourceUrl);
        /****************/
        audio[0].pause();
        audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element

        //audio[0].play(); changed based on Sprachprofi's comment below
        audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();
        /****************/
    }
```

And of course HTML

```
 <audio id="Lecteur" controls="controls">
  <source id="SRC"  type="audio/mp4" />
</audio>
```

It's working well on FF and IE, when i change ID file sound stop and strat immediatlly (before file are complet downloaded), on Chrome it's not so good 
But not working in iOS...:(

What are best practice for that juste streaming audio files to HTML player...
maybe with jquery plugin, but witch?

Thank

Comment: You are calling `.play` immediately at `audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();` instead of referencing `.play` function `audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play;`

Comment: you mean 
 audio.on('canplaythrough', function () {
                audio[0].play();
            });
?? the same

Comment: Yes, you could alternatively use `this.play()` within handler

Comment: Yes but it's same result on iOS no play starting, file is charging but not played

Comment: Why is `MIME` type set to `audio/m4a` at server, though `audio/mp4` at `<source>` element?

Comment: Yes I change it to mpeg... But same canplaythrough is not firing

Comment: no sorry it's working with same MIME type...!